# What is the difference between Ajaxl load(() and Jquery load()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

The question summarizes what i intend to know . I know a little bit about the jquery load() method having used it before like this :

```
.load( url, [ data ], [ complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ] )
```

where,

url - A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
data - A map or string that is sent to the server with the request.
complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) - A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

But what is this Ajax load() method that crops up a lot in the internet ? What's the big difference between the two ?

I could have searched that out in the internet, but i thought i will rather ask the experts here as i always `stack` before i `google` :). Thanks

Comment: Which Ajax load? Could you point us to some references, please?

Comment: AJAX is simply the technology that allows you to load data/page/etc. asynchronously.  jQuery `load` is a function to actually do such loading using jQuery framework.

Comment: @AleksG : So basically jquery is the framework which helps in executing the `load()` method, which is essentially an ajax method ?

Comment: @limelights : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_load.asp . It comes up as a subset of jquery methods in w3c, bit is referred to as Ajax-Jquery load() . Hence i was confused .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight it says right there that it's using a jquery method.

Comment: @limelights Yes it does that, but also refers to Ajax there, so i was thinking about whether those are 2 separate methods . Seems like they are the one .

Comment: Where in the world does it refer to ajax load()? Nowhere. The url is /jquery/ajax_load - dead giveaway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what is this Ajax load() method that crops up a lot in the internet ?

There's no such method. The [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method is the one that you are seeing in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, got it now, thanks though for the reply .